# How to setup and run a JavaScript/Vue GitHub project locally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm

I have an app located here that I cloned: [cvss-v4-calculator](https://github.com/RedHatProductSecurity/cvss-v4-calculator) that I want to run locally so I can debug it using VS Code or something similar, however I'm running into issues trying to figure out how to implement this? I've been trying to get node.js to load this as a web page, but I'm not clear if this is the best approach.

I've not setup a GitHub JavaScript app, nor used Vue before, so this could be something simple.  However, it references Vue in the app.js file which throws this error when I used the npm run command: **ReferenceError: Vue is not defined** which is coming from this line of code: `const app = Vue.createApp({ ...` in the app.js.

Also, there is a reference to the Vue cdn in index.html:
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.45/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>` and it's at the top of the scripts, so I would have thought it would have resolved itself.

I also don't see any dist, node_modules, vue folders, nor a package.json.  I assumed I had to build all of them, but I'm not sure if that is correct or what is needed for this to run?

I can open the HTML file in a browser so it runs that way, but I'm wanting to debug things line by line.  Any ideas as to what I need to do and the steps for this to run in some debugger?

Comment: This appears to be covered in their [quick-start documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html)...

Comment: This particular project was made in a way so that it has no build step.  You are meant to directly open `index.html` in your browser.

Comment: Have you considered asking the only people who know whether they even intended for you to use this, [over on their issue tracker](https://github.com/RedHatProductSecurity/cvss-v4-calculator/issues)? The README.md has no instructions, that could be intentional, or could be "oh yeah we never did, let me add how to run this right now" and an hour later you have the documentation you were looking for. But more importantly, _so will everyone else_ =) If an open source project is lacking docs, always ask the maintainers. Worse case they'll say you're on your own, and then SO might make sense.

Comment: It carries the BSD 2-Clause "Simplified" License, so there are no legal restrictions for using it, especially in this case as it's for educational purposes.

Comment: – Heretic Monkey I'll take a look at it.  What is odd is why they reference the vue cnn, but only have one line that references Vue, which is the create.  I was able to create a simple Vue app using the vue cli, but that doesn't seem like what they are doing here.

Comment: It's not just "one line".  Everything inside of `createApp({ ... })`, which is basically the entire app.js file, is Vue (or the script part of it), which mounts to index.html.  You can also see in index.html a lot references to the different methods and data variables defined in the Vue app (also `@click` handlers, [text interpolation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#text-interpolation), special Vue directives like `v-if`, etc.).  All this HTML combined with app.js comprises the Vue app.

Comment: It is maybe an uncommon way of using Vue, but [perfectly acceptable](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#using-vue-from-cdn)

Comment: Okay, my misunderstanding of Vue then.  Never used it before.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is the offical response from the maintainers:

> From my own perspective, I used to open the index.html file in a
> browser and use console.log to "debug". It's far from being perfect
> but the current Vue setup has a complete rework to do to be a real
> front-end server. FYI we know this issue in the FIRST.ORG SIG CVSS and
> discussed it, but no work was performed in this direction.

So, while it's not ideal, I'll use console.log rather than try to rework the Vue code.

Comment: Can't you just use the regular debugger of your browser?

Comment: Yes or use debug to stop execution.  I prefer using an IDE though.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging - you can also debug your index.html with VSCode (search for "without running a server" on the page)

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't aware of this, obviously.